# How to do this?

Tags: r

I have a problem and I would ask if is a function or easy way to do below operation.

I have a data.frame like this

```
customer     item
-------------------
smith         a
smith         b
smith         c
johnson       a
bush          NA
regan         d
```

How to create matrix like this

```
customer    a   b  c  d 
--------------------------------------
smith       1   1  1  0
johnson     1   0  0  0
bush        0   0  0  0
regan       0   0  0  1
```

Is loop obligartory? Is easier way to create this? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: You just killed your own question.

Comment: I would like to ask if is a function like group by ...i created matrix byt i have a problem with fil it.

Comment: Try `table` on your data.frame

Answer (score 0):

You should use the table function.  The call would look something like this.  IT goes `x,y` but depending on what the full data.frame list looks you may want to add some more parameters to handle NA values and such

```
table(df$customer, df$item)
```